# read data and send data to a database

Tags: http-get

I'm trying to use an android app with my data base. I know how to retrieve and send information to the data base, but I don't know how to do it in Android.
When I type the URL, lets say "http://01.01.001.001/api/example" in the browser, I can see this:

```
<ArrayOfArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<ArrayOfstring>
<string>52</string>
<string>Pregunta español prueba 52</string>
<string>NO</string>
<string>SI</string>
<string>NO</string>
<string/>
<string/>
<string/>
<string/>
<string/>
<string/>
<string/>
<string i:nil="true"/>
</ArrayOfstring>
<ArrayOfstring>
<string>53</string>
<string>Pregunta 53 NIVEL 2</string>
<string>NO</string>
<string>53 mucho</string>
<string>53 Algo</string>
<string>53 Nada</string>
<string>53 Poco</string>
<string>53 Fin</string>
<string i:nil="true"/>
<string i:nil="true"/>
<string i:nil="true"/>
<string i:nil="true"/>
<string i:nil="true"/>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

which is a bunch of strings. How can I place each string in a variable in android? If I try

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
    InputStream content = null;
    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Execute HTTP Get Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle the exception !
    }
    return content;

}
```

The content is always null when using the URL. Once the content is not null, how can I translate it to a set of strings?

Thanks a lot!